# Do not understand this line of code in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, abstract-class

I am reading to some piece of code written by some experienced programmer, and I do not understand some part of it. Unfortunately, I am new to Python programming.

This is the line of code which confuses me:

```
realworld = ConcreteRealWorldScheduler(RealWorldScenario(newscenario)).schedule()
```

To generalize I will rewrite it again

```
variable = OneConcreteClass(OneClass(anotherVariable)).method()
```

This part confuses me the most:

```
(RealWorldScenario(newscenario))
```

If someone could give me a thorough description it would be very helpful.

THanks

Comment: `RealWorldScenario(newscenario)` means object of `RealWorldScenario` class is being constructed with variable `newscenario`.

Comment: I'm not sure why the inner instantiation confuses you, but the outer one does not.

Comment: Do you know about classes in python and the `__init__` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as:

```
# New object, newscenario passed to constructor
world_scenario = RealWordScenario(newscenario)
# Another new object, now world_scenario is passed to constructor
scheduler = ConcreteRealWorldScheduler(world_scenario)
# Call the method
variable = scheduler.method()
```

Answer (score 1):

It may seem confusing due to the naming, or the complexity of the classes, but this is essentially the same as:

```
foo = set(list('bar')).pop()
```

So, in this example:

1. First of all a `list` is being instantiated with `'bar'`

   - `list('bar') == ['b', 'a', 'r']`
2. Next a set is created from the list

   - `set(['b', 'a', 'r']) == {'a', 'b', 'r'}`
3. Then we use `set`'s the `pop()` method

   - `{'a', 'b', 'r'}.pop()` will return `'a'` and leave the `set` as `{'b', 'r'}`

So the same is true of your given line of code:

```
realworld = ConcreteRealWorldScheduler(RealWorldScenario(newscenario)).schedule()
```

1. First a new `RealWorldScenario` is instantiated with `newscenario`
2. Next, a `ConcreteRealWorldScheduler` is instantiated with the `RealWorldScenario` instance
3. Finally, the `schedule()` method of the `ConcreteRealWorldScheduler` instance is called.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the outside instead, we have

```
variable = OneConcreteClass(OneClass(anotherVariable)).method()
```

or

```
variable = SomethingConfusing.method()
```

We conclude `SomethingConfusing` is an object with a method called `method`

What else do we know?
Well, it's really

```
OneConcreteClass(OneClass(anotherVariable))
```

or

```
OneConcreteClass(SomethingElseConfusing)
```

`OneConreteClass` is thus a concrete class which takes another object in its `__init__` method, specifically something of type `OneClass` which has been initialised with `OneClass(anotherVariable)`

For further details see [Dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985806/python-constructors-and-init)

Answer (score 0):

In Python almost everything is `Object`

so when we create instance to an object we do something like this:

```
obj = ClassName()  # class itself an object of "Type"
```

or
    obj = ClassName(Args)  # Here args are passed to the constructor

if your class has any member called `method()`

you can do like as follows:

```
obj.method()
```

or

```
ClassName().method()
```